# "UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION" when trying to deploy Permission Set

Tags: metadata-api, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I'm trying to deploy an app to a packaging (Developer Edition) org. I successfully pulled the source from a scratch org and successfully converted the source using `force:source:convert`.

I run the following command:

```
sudo sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d metadata -u [my username] -w -1 --verbose --loglevel trace
```

...and the CLI outputs the following:

```
=== Result
Status:  Failed
jobid:  0Af1I00000TWEFPSA5
Completed:  2017-11-29T20:38:01.000Z
Component errors:  0
Components deployed:  182
Components total:  244
Tests errors:  0
Tests completed:  0
Tests total:  0
Check only: false
```

I see the following line in the sfdx.log file (log level was set to 'trace'):

```
\"errorMessage\":\"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: EXTERNAL_OBJECT_EXCEPTION: Could not locate metadata file: IotPsl-1.uld.xml\",\"errorStatusCode\":\"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION\",\"id\":\"0Af1I00000TWEFPSA5\"
```

I don't know what the `IotPsl-1.uld.xml` file is or why the error is an EXTERNAL_OBJECT_EXCEPTION.

Any information on what this error means or how to resolve it would be helpful.

EDIT:

I removed the permission set folder from the metadata directory, ran the mdapi:deploy command, and the operation succeeded. This was an educated guess based on the "[Known Limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_considerations.htm)" docs, which mentions that an "Unknown" error will be thrown when running the `force:source:push` command after removing a permission set locally.

While I did *not* remove the permission set locally, nor did I have a problem with the `force:source:push` command I guessed that the issues might be related to permission sets.

Any information on what might be the root cause of the problem or if this is a DX bug would be helpful.

EDIT:

I verified that I cannot create or modify any further permission sets via the metadata api and through the UI. The permission set screen in SF displays the following message:

[image]

Comment: I don't think its a DX bug. We've run into this issue today with our appexchange package (in code that uses the Metadata API) and I also saw a tweet that someone got this error while trying to uninstall a different appexchange package.

Comment: To clarify above, it was actually code that that queries `PermissionSet` and `PermissionSetAssignment`

Comment: Did you also encounter the error pictured above when attempting to modify permission sets through the GUI?

Comment: Yes, my coworker observed that as well.

Comment: We faced the same issue in our developer edition org. We also zeroed it down to PermissionSet. It is not related to DX.

Comment: I faced it on eu9 data center. On na40 I can select PermissionSet without any error.

Comment: I think this might be an internal Salesforce issue because we also got it on the Salesforce Custom Permission Set page.

Comment: We've logged a case with SF, if anyone else wants to do the same that might help escalate the issue.

Comment: I've logged a case as well and they told me they will call us today. I will post any more information I find out from that call.

Comment: Did you hear from them?

Comment: Not yet, I had to re-schedule the call for today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Known issue published, they are patching tonight.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCtbQAE

Answer (score 0):

1. Known issue is already marked as resolved.
   https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCtbQAE
2. We are facing this issue in one of org, any solution or workaround ?
3. We are querying PermissionSetAssignment in code.
4. Permission Set listing in Salesforce throws 
   An internal server error has occurred